# How do I copy an ArrayIterator to preserve it's current iteration position?

Tags: php, arrays, iterator, copy

Because this seems like what I have to do to get this effect:

```
$arr = ['a'=>'first', 'b'=>'second', ...];
$iter = new ArrayIterator( $arr );

// Do a bunch of iterations...
$iter->next();
// ...

$new_iter = new ArrayIterator( $arr );
while( $new_iter->key() != $iter->key() ) {
    $new_iter->next();
}
```

Edit: Also, just to be clear, should I NOT be modifying the base array with `unset()`? I figure the array iterator stores its own copy of the base array, so using `offsetUnset()` doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ArrayIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) does not implement a `tell()` function, but you can emulate this, and then use [`seek()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.seek.php) to go to the position you want. Here's an extended class that does just that:

```
<?php
    class ArrayIteratorTellable extends ArrayIterator {
        private $position = 0;

        public function next() {
            $this->position++;
            parent::next();
        }

        public function rewind() {
            $this->position = 0;
            parent::rewind();
        }

        public function seek($position) {
            $this->position = $position;
            parent::seek($position);
        }

        public function tell() {
            return $this->position;
        }

        public function copy() {
            $clone = clone $this;
            $clone->seek($this->tell());
            return $clone;
        }
    }
?>
```

### Use:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a' => 'first', 'b' => 'second', 'c' => 'third', 'd' => 'fourth');
    $iter = new ArrayIteratorTellable( $arr );

    $iter->next();

    $new_iter = new ArrayIteratorTellable( $arr );

    var_dump($iter->current()); //string(6) "second"
    var_dump($new_iter->current()); //string(6) "first"

    $new_iter->seek($iter->tell()); //Set the pointer to the same as $iter

    var_dump($new_iter->current()); //string(6) "second"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/LQaJOSMg)

---

Alternately, you can use the custom `copy()` function to clone the object:

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a' => 'first', 'b' => 'second', 'c' => 'third', 'd' => 'fourth');
    $iter = new ArrayIteratorTellable( $arr );

    $iter->next();

    $new_iter = $iter->copy();

    var_dump($iter->current()); //string(6) "second"
    var_dump($new_iter->current()); //string(6) "second"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/dqs12QQs)

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I thought of is using a copy of current array

```
$arr = ['a'=>'first', 'b'=>'second'];
$iter = new ArrayIterator( $arr );
// Do a bunch of iterations...
$iter->next();
var_dump($iter->current());
// ...
$arr2 = $iter->getArrayCopy();
$new_iter = new ArrayIterator( $arr2 );

while( $new_iter->key() != $iter->key() ) {
    var_dump($new_iter->current());
    $new_iter->next();    
}
```

Comment: How does copying the current array preserve its iteration position?

Comment: seems that I have misuderstood a bit, if you want to preserve the position the best solution is that h2ooooooo provided.