# How do i clone an ArrayIterator in PHP?

Tags: php, clone, arrayiterator

I am trying to clone an \ArrayIterator object, but it seems like the cloned one is still referencing to the original one.

```
$list = new \ArrayIterator;
$list->append('a');
$list->append('b');

$list2 = clone $list;
$list2->append('c');
$list2->append('d');

// below result prints '4', i am expecting result '2'
echo $list->count();
```

Anyone have explanation to this behavior? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Though I am having difficulty locating documentation that explicitly says so, internally `ArrayIterator`'s private `$storage` property wherein the array is held must be a reference to an array rather than the array itself directly stored within the object.

The [documentation on `clone`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) says that

> PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables will remain references.

So when you `clone` the `ArrayIterator` object, the newly cloned object contains a reference to the same array as the original one.  [Here is an old bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36941) wherein this behavior is said to be the expected behavior.

If you want to copy the current state of an `ArrayIterator`, you might consider instead instantiating a new one using the array [returned by `getArrayCopy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.getarraycopy.php)

```
$iter = new \ArrayIterator([1,2,3,4,5]);

// Copy out the array to instantiate a new one
$copy = new \ArrayIterator($iter->getArrayCopy());
// Modify it
$copy->append(6);

var_dump($iter); // unmodified
php > var_dump($iter);
class ArrayIterator#1 (1) {
  private $storage =>
  array(5) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(2)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
    [3] =>
    int(4)
    [4] =>
    int(5)
  }
}

var_dump($copy); // modified
class ArrayIterator#2 (1) {
  private $storage =>
  array(6) {
    [0] =>
    int(1)
    [1] =>
    int(2)
    [2] =>
    int(3)
    [3] =>
    int(4)
    [4] =>
    int(5)
    [5] =>
    int(6)
  }
}
```

The above is a simple operation though, and only creates a new `ArrayIterator` with the currently stored array as the original. It does *not* maintain the current iteration state. To do that, you would need to also call `seek()` to advance the pointer to the desired position. [Here is a thorough answer explaining how that could be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20069139/541091).

Comment: I was also looking for the same documentation but as it says `Warning
This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available.` I was also thinking about the same reference issue, as you explained, "'the array is held must be a reference to an array rather than the array itself directly stored within the object." But after testing myself, I see it's not referring some external array. But it stores the array inside, which then it keeps as reference when cloning. I don't know actual reason for it, but based on this scenario, the sentence above is not 100% accurate.

Comment: You can test it with this, `$myArray = array('m'); $list = new ArrayIterator($myArray);` (Later you will see that, the ArrayIterator doesn't impact the original `$myArray` for it's future operations.)

Comment: I tested that as well - the reference is not to the original array variable passed to the iterator - it is an internal reference to an array otherwise inaccessible to PHP code, copied from the array variable passed to the iterator.  If it were a reference to the _original_ variable, that would make the iterator's state potentially inconsistent.

Comment: I hoped to be able to inspect it with a ReflectionProperty, but on an internal class it seems it isn't possible to retrieve private properties. In any case, that bug report I linked does clearly state that this behavior is intended. "_If you clone an ArrayIterator you also clone its reference thus the described behavior below is correct._"

Answer (score 1):

Completing what has been said before, if you are trying to clone a class that *inherits* from `ArrayIterator`, you can use this method in order to automatically clone the stored array :

```
public function __clone(){
    parent::__construct($this->getArrayCopy());
}
```